# Installing numpy in gcloud App Engine running Node.js runtime (or even custom runtime). Running fine locally but getting errors when deployed

Tags: python, node.js, docker, google-app-engine

I am currently deploying node.js based server on google cloud app engine which calls python script to process some data.

**As a brief overview, my code is execute as such:**

1. Front-end html posts a data to the server
2. Server receives the data
3. Node.js calls python script and passes on the data as an async function in the background
4. Data handling is done

**Problem:**

The python process uses numpy and matplotlib libraries which is imported fine locally.

But when deployed, it seems to be having trouble importing these libraries on the App Engine.

**Error that I am receiving:**

```
Error: ImportError: No module named numpy
at PythonShell.parseError (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:260)
at terminateIfNeeded (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:139)
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/python-shell/index.js:131)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:248)
```

**Things that I have tried:**

1. in app.yaml

   - Changing the running environment to *custom* from *nodejs*
   - Modifying the docker file and trying installing numpy there.

Lines added on the top of dockerfile:

```
    FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
    RUN virtualenv /env
    ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
    ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
    ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
    RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
    ADD . /app
```

**requirements.txt:**

`numpy==1.6.1`

which compiles fine but still gives me the
`Error: ImportError: No module named numpy`
error.

2. On the python process, initiate a python process beforehand and try to install numpy before initializing the main processing script *(I know this is not a good idea since it'll download numpy every time the process happens, but I desperately wanted to get it **at least working in any way possible**)*

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
pythonProcess = spawn('python',["-m","pip", "install", "numpy", "matplotlib"]);
```

which produces an error as such:

```
Error: Python Process Recieved: /usr/bin/python: No module named pip
at Socket.pythonProcess.stderr.on (analysis.js:286)
at Socket.emit (events.js:198)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:288)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:269)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224)
at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94)
```

I have read some documentations online and it seems that these libraries can be imported if you are running `runtime:python27` and add libraries there by doing  but my application is 99% node.js and python processing part is just a small part of the application.

I am so lost as to how to get these solved.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to install PIP on your custom runtime by adding

RUN apt-get install python-pip

this is my Dockerfile for this example

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
RUN apt-get install python-pip
RUN virtualenv /env
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
ADD . /app
```